# Inconsistent display when a Java Swing program runs

Tags: java, swing, bluej

I am relatively new to Java(especially swing) and I am using BlueJ IDE for some basic Swing programs.
The problem is that when I run it, the output of the code shows no consistency!
Sometimes it gets displayed properly with all the components , but at other times it only displays upto the green panel but not any components inside it that I have added.  The components suddenly appear if I maximize or drag the window and increase it's size in those cases.
I would say only about one in 3 or 4 times it runs correctly. What is happening and how can I prevent it?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class Swing16
{
public static void main()
{


JFrame frame1 = new JFrame("TESTING");

frame1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame1.setVisible(true);
frame1.setSize(1000,700);
frame1.setLocation(200,100);
//frame1.setResizable(false);


frame1.setLayout(null);


JPanel pan1 = new JPanel();
pan1.setBackground(Color.green);
pan1.setBounds(0,0,900,600);
frame1.add(pan1);


pan1.setLayout(null);

JButton east = new JButton("East");
JButton west = new JButton("West");
JButton north = new JButton("North");
JButton south = new JButton("South");


Color cr1 = new Color(0,127,0);
Font ft1 =new Font("impact",Font.BOLD,25);



north.setForeground(Color.white);
north.setBackground(cr1);

south.setForeground(Color.white);
south.setBackground(cr1);

east.setForeground(Color.white);
east.setBackground(Color.blue);
east.setFont(ft1);
east.setToolTipText(" This is the EAST zone");

west.setForeground(Color.white);
west.setBackground(Color.blue);
west.setFont(ft1);
west.setToolTipText(" This is the WEST zone");




JLabel lb1 = new  JLabel(" Label 1 ");

JLabel lb2 = new  JLabel(" Label 2 ");
lb2.setOpaque(true);
lb2.setForeground(Color.white);
lb2.setBackground(Color.black);
lb2.setFont(ft1);



JTextField tf1 =new JTextField(" TextField1");
tf1.setForeground(Color.white);
tf1.setBackground(Color.black);
tf1.setFont(ft1);
//tf1.selectAll();

JTextField tf2 =new JTextField("TextField 2");
//tf2.getFocus();

JTextArea ta1= new JTextArea("Enter TA",5,30);
ta1.setForeground(Color.white);
ta1.setBackground(Color.black);
//ta1.setFont(ft1);




east.setBounds(400,200,80,100);
pan1.add(east);

west.setBounds(20,200,80,100);
pan1.add(west);

north.setBounds(200,10,100,80);
pan1.add(north);

south.setBounds(200,510,100,80);
pan1.add(south);



lb1.setBounds(0,0,100,50);
pan1.add(lb1);
lb2.setBounds(0,80,100,50);
pan1.add(lb2);


tf1.setBounds(10,350,80,30);
pan1.add(tf1);
tf2.setBounds(10,500,80,30);
pan1.add(tf2);



ta1.setBounds(400,10,100,180);
pan1.add(ta1);




}
}
```

Comment: For the love of god, please format your code next time. Ctrl+Shift+F for Eclipse, Ctrl+Alt+L for IntellijIDEA.

Comment: P.S. Your problem is definitelly in calling `setVisible` before adding components.

Comment: Yes, that solved it. Thanks! Can you explain why?

Comment: Accept MadProgrammers answer then.

Answer (score 3):

Three things jump out...

1. You are not constructing your UI within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread
2. You are using `null` layouts
3. You are calling `setVisible(true)` on the frame before you've completed building your UI.

Start by making sure that you start you program within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread...

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            // Construct your UI here...
        }
    });
}
```

See [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) for more details...

Not every system is the same.  They may have different font metrics, DPI, screen resolutions, graphics pipelines, etc... all which will affect how your UI is rendered.  To this end, you should be making use of appropriate layout managers.

Take a look at [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)

And lastly, you should avoid calling `setVisible` on the frame until you've completed constructing you UI, on some systems, this can present a blank frame

Comment: Thanks for your help. I made frame1.setVisible(true) the last line in the code and now it displays correctly everytime. I don't know much about threads.I plan on getting there after Swing and AWT. I deliberately chose to experiment with the null Layout.

Comment: You don't need to know much about threads at this stage, other than the fact that the UI runs within it's own thread and you are required to ensure that any modifications you make to the UI are made from within the context of this thread...